# XPages Managed Bean and Repeat Control issue: how to reload value?

Tags: xpages, repeater, managed-bean

For my XPage I developed some Managed Beans to keep data. The page itself contains a Repeat control, it's like this at the moment:

```
<xp:panel styleClass="form">
    <xp:this.dataContexts>
        <xp:dataContext value="#{javascript:PageData.getForm(compositeData.formName, compositeData.dataSource);}"
            var="myFormData">
        </xp:dataContext>
        <xp:dataContext var="myFields">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return myFormData.getFieldsAsJSON();}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:dataContext>
    </xp:this.dataContexts>
    <xp:table style="width:100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
        <xp:repeat var="thisfield" rows="#{javascript:compositeData.rows}" disableTheme="true" repeatControls="true"
            disableOutputTag="true" value="#{myFields}">
```

The PageData object is a bean, it contains info about a form and its fields. The dropdown fields contain options, but they can be dynamically created. When that happens, as a result of a partial refresh, the form is redisplayed but... the repeat 'value' itself (myFields) isn't reloaded into the repeat, so new dropdown options aren't made available.

How can I make XPages reload the 'value' property?

UPDATE
More info, as requested...

From the FormData bean:

```
public Object getFieldsAsJSON() {
    ArrayObject list = null;

    try {
        System.err.print("FormData: getFieldsAsJSON");
        list = new ArrayObject();
        for (Entry<String, FieldData> e : fields.entrySet()) {
            FieldData field = e.getValue();
            list.addArrayValue(field.getJSON());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return list;
}
```

and from the FieldData bean:

```
public ObjectObject getJSON() throws InterpretException {
    ObjectObject json = new ObjectObject();
    json.put("name", FBSUtility.wrap(name));
    json.put("label", FBSUtility.wrap(field.getLabel()));
    json.put("options", FBSUtility.wrap(values));
    return json;
}
```

IMHO the problem isn't in these beans. It's more an XPages issue, because for some strange reason the structure is only fetched once, and never again. Apparently, XPages considers the json to be static, which it isn't.

Before the bean-era, I had everything in SSJS, creating the JavaScript object on the fly, and it was reloaded every time. Why not anymore, what is the difference? Is there something to tell XPages that the repeat-value is 'stale' and should be re-read?

Comment: I now do have a work-araound: the object isn't re-evaluated, and thisfield in the example above isn't changed, but... myFields[indexVar].options is !

Answer (score 0):

With your current code myFormData and myFields will be recalculated during every partial refresh as well. Is that necessary?

I'm not certain, but looking at what you're seeing, I suspect the repeat control needs the contents of the dataContexts at a particular phase of the XPages lifecycle. But the dataContexts will be recalculated at every phase of the XPages lifecycle, which may result in them being null when the repeat wants to use the values.

My best advice is to debug what's happening at which phases in the partial refresh. You'll probably need to change your code to work around what's calculated when.

I'm not convinced dataContexts set to be computed dynamically are a good approach unless you're using them for rendered properties or read-only data. If you're using a managed bean, lazy-loading the data and retrieving it directly from the bean may be a better approach, as well as making it easier to identify when it's being called.

Comment: Those DataContexts are the most recent attempt to make it work. I had it entirely without them, directly getting data from the bean, with the same result. I do need the code to be re-executed, and I have some debugging in the calls to the beans that tells me that the contexts are updated indeed. Unlike the Repeat Control value...

Comment: How about changing the repeat's value property to be SSJS, including a log statement. Using XPages OpenLog Logger, you would be able to see the earliest phase it's triggered in, from the stack trace (if the same message is captured for the same component in multiple phases, it only logs it once; but including @Unique() you could get every phase).

Comment: It's EL right now, but it used to be SSJS, there were no DataContexts at all. The log I had as well, using my own logging there, but it isn't even called on a partial refresh.

Comment: Suggest you add the pertinent code from the Bean itself.  That might be worthwhile to see.